# Eclipse: How to disable wrapping & indentation for conditionals

Tags: java, eclipse

I would like to achieve following format of ternary if-operator in `Eclipse 4.2 (Juno)`:

```
String value = cond1 ? val1 :
               cond2 ? val2 :
               cond3 ? val3 :
               raise(new IllegalStateException("One of the conditions should be true"));
```

But after struggling with configuration in `Preferences -> Formatter -> Edit profile -> Line wrapping -> Conditionals` I can't achieve anything similar.

Eclipse either does this:

```
String value = cond1 ? val1 :
cond2 ? val2 :
cond3 ? val3 :
raise(new IllegalStateException("One of the conditions should be true"));
```

or this:

```
String value = cond1 ? val1 :
                   cond2 ? val2 :
                       cond3 ? val3 :
                           raise(new IllegalStateException("One of the conditions should be true"));
```

Am I missing something or it's not possible to disable wrapping or indentation in such cases at least?

Is it possible to achieve something similar in `Eclipse 4.3 (Kepler)` ?

Are there any decent Eclipse formatting plugins out there to solve my case?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First, you must create a new Java formatter in:

`Preferences > Java > Formatter`

Then, just enable the option `Never join already wrapped lines` in the `Line Wrapping` tab in the formatter edit menu. It's easy as that!

This option is useful for all kind of wrappings that take more than a single line.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a `formatter`.

```
Preferences -> Java -> Formatter
```

And then set the `save actions`

```
Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Save Actions
```

Comment: Yes, I've already done this. The question is: how to configure `conditionals` formatting options to achieve desired result?